# Excel Combine Named Range

Tags: excel

I have a named range titled 'CityLocation'. If I want to refer to this named range elsewhere in a formula, I can just write something such as `=COUNTA(CityLocation)`. However, if I try `=COUNTA("City"&"Location")`, then I get a completely different output. Looking at the Evaluate Formula tool, it seems that the latter methodology tried to calculate `=COUNTA("CityLocation")` rather than `=COUNTA(CityLocation)`.

Is there any way to combine (in this example) City and Location without the inverted commas?

Comment: Without inverted commas - you mean `=COUNTA(City,Location)` is not acceptable?

Comment: City or Location are not values themselves, so `=COUNTA(City,Location)` doesn't work. Neither are City or Location named ranges in and of themselves - they only become a named range when combined as CityLocation

Comment: If you have named ranged as CITYLOCATION then =COUNTA(CITYLOCATION) must work.

Comment: Yes, `=COUNTA(CityLocation)` does indeed work. The problem occurs when I try combining it via `=COUNTA("City"&"Location")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use indirect.

`=COUNTA(INDIRECT("City"&"Location"))`

Comment: This doesn't work, and I'm not sure how INDIRECT would help here. Regardless, Excel understands this as `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("CityLocation")` rather than `=COUNTA(INDRECT(CityLocation)` - my challenge is in having Excel calculate this without any inverted commas (").

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't your goal to evaluate `=COUNTA(INDRECT(CityLocation)` while composing the name of the range piecemeal? This is accomplished using the indirect, which evaluates to the same as the formula without the inverted commas. If that doesn't work, can you help me understand what is your desired result?

Comment: to clarify my comment above: `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("CityLocation"))` is identical to `=COUNTA(CityLocation)`

Comment: Thanks @PlasticSoul - ignore my last message, what you have written makes sense. I have realised that this doesn't work for me is due to the fact that CityLocation is a dynamic named range, which seemingly don't work with the INDIRECT function. I'll accept the answer though as I didn't make this clear in the question.

Comment: @NatAes hmm, yes, that's interesting. I didn't realize that Dynamic Named Ranges can't be referenced by `INDIRECT`. It just occurred to me that perhaps you can compose the range dynamically in another cell, and then use `INDIRECT` to point to that cell (instead of specifying the named range). Maybe that will be helpful to you, maybe not. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two ranges by entering them as a comma separated list.  You could define a new range with the definition `=City,Location`, then do a `=COUNTA` on that named range.

Of course in a formula, that would look like multiple parameters. You can make it clear it is only one parameter by enclosing the comma separated list in its own parentheses:

```
=COUNTA((City,Location))
```